# Why largest cats so much larger than canids?

Tags: evolution, physiology

It is striking to me that there is no dog-like creature larger than a wolf while there are at least two species, tigers and lions, many (at least twice and probably 3 or 4) times the size of the largest wolves. I would guess it has something to do with hunting style, packs vs individual hunters although lions do sometimes attack in groups. I am not saying I would like one to exist, but why is there nothing like a 400-500 pound wolf?